# How to define input to keep float number in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

My requirements:

- input must keep float number, letters and other characters are disallowed
- in state it should be kept as number, not string, because of many calculation are done on it
- I would like to prevent leading zeroes to be shown in input e.g. 000123.45

My code:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class App extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        Quantity: 0,
    }
    static propTypes = {
        Quantity: PropTypes.number,
        HandleQuantityChange: PropTypes.func,
    } 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    } 

    render(){
        return (
            <div style={{padding:'30px'}}>
                <input 
                    type='number'
                    name='quantity' 
                    value={this.props.Quantity != null ? this.props.Quantity : ''}
                    onChange={this.props.HandleQuantityChange} 
                    onBlur={this.props.HandleQuantityChange} 
                    onKeyUp={this.props.HandleQuantityChange} 
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

AppContainer.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import App from './App'

export default class AppContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            quantity: 0
        }
    }

    handleQuantityChange = (e) => {
        if(e.type === 'blur' || e.key === 'Enter'){
            console.log('blur', e.target.value)
            const newQuantity = e.target.value != '' ? parseFloat(e.target.value) : 0
            this.setState({
                quantity: newQuantity
            })            
        } else {
            const newQuantity = e.target.value != '' ? parseFloat(e.target.value) : null
            this.setState({
                quantity: newQuantity
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <App
                Quantity={ this.state.quantity }
                HandleQuantityChange={this.handleQuantityChange}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

If-else construction in handler is to distinguish 'entering in progress' ( `else` ) to 'final number entered' ( `if` ). Without this I couldn't enter negative number, because simple character "-" is not a number and cannot be parsed by `parseFloat()`.

In current version of my code I still have problem with leading zeroes - what should I change?

Comment: You can try: parseFloat(e.target.value.replace(/^0+/, ''));

Comment: just to clarify, you want the user to only be able to enter numbers in the inputs including float number and negative numbers. All other characters must not be allowed, right?

Comment: @Yousaf - exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found solution fulfilling requirements ( code below ).

Because react compares value in input with passing `value` prop, first converting both to numbers, there is no difference between `000.123` in input and `0.123` in state so the value `000.123` remains unchanged. That's why I do `setState` twice: first with something different than current value and next with real value to set.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class App extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        Quantity: 0,
    }
    static propTypes = {
        Quantity: PropTypes.number,
        HandleQuantityChange: PropTypes.func,
    } 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    } 

    render(){
        return (
                <input 
                    type='number'
                    name='quantity' 
                    value={this.props.Quantity != null ? this.props.Quantity : ''}
                    onChange={this.props.HandleQuantityChange} 
                    onBlur={this.props.HandleQuantityChange} 
                    onKeyUp={this.props.HandleQuantityChange} 
                />
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

AppContainer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import App from './App'

export default class AppContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            quantity: 0
        }
    }

    handleQuantityChange = (e) => {
        if(e.type === 'blur' || e.key === 'Enter'){
            const quantityWithRemovedLeadingZeroes = e.target.value != '' ? parseFloat(e.target.value) : 0
            const tempNumberToChange = quantityWithRemovedLeadingZeroes === 0 ? 1 : 0
            this.setState({ quantity: tempNumberToChange }, () => {
                this.setState({ quantity: quantityWithRemovedLeadingZeroes })
            })

        } else if(e.type==='change') {
            const newQuantity = e.target.value != '' ? parseFloat(e.target.value) : null
            this.setState({
                quantity: newQuantity
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <App
                Quantity={ this.state.quantity }
                HandleQuantityChange={this.handleQuantityChange}
            />
        )
    }
}
```